# Automatically update a field after having filled another field

Tags: strapi

I'm very new to Strapi and I'm a self-taught developer, so please bear with me if it's not a very intelligent question.

I'm on Strapi v4.15.4 (node v20.8.0) and I have an `article` collection type with 3 numeric attributes `number1`, `number2` and `total`.

What I'm trying to do is to automatically update the `total` attribute, summing `number1` and `number2`, every time `number1` or `number2` is updated.

So far, I was able to edit `src\api\article\content-types\article\lifecycles.js` as follow:

```
module.exports = {
    async beforeCreate(event) {
      if (event.params.data.number2) {
        event.params.data.total = event.params.data.number1 + event.params.data.number2;
      }
    },
    async beforeUpdate(event) {
      if (event.params.data.number2) {
        event.params.data.total = event.params.data.number1 + event.params.data.number2;
      }
    },
};
```

The code above actually works when I click the 'Save' button, when creating/editing an entry in the `article` collection type, from the admin panel. However I can't find a way to make it work right after updating the `number1` or `number2` attributes.

Any advice is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That’s not going to work straight away… you can do that via a custom json field. But you would loose ability to filter on all three fields.

Comment: Thanks @antokhio, could you please give me a quick example on how to do it with a custom json field?

Comment: There was a nice blogspot on customFields, but can't find it for whatever reason, you can start from https://github.com/strapi/strapi/tree/main/packages/plugins/color-picker and https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/custom-fields

Comment: Thank you verry much @antokhio, I'll take a look at the links.